# how to use the data gateway of microsoft power bi

Tags: powerbi

after successfully creating a data source in 'manage data gateway' (meaning was installed successfully), how do I used them? how to connect the web/desktop power bi version to this data gateway? even it can refresh the data to latest how does the two system connect to this data gateway? it seems the tutorial from Microsoft power bi website only talks about how it is communicating with each other but did not show any tutorial as to where to setup a connection between power bi desktop/web to use the data gateway

Comment: Which gateway have you set up? Personal or enterprise? What kind of data source are you trying to connect? Which tutorial are you looking at? Where in the tutorial did you get stuck? You don't have to do anything special to use the gateway. In Power BI Desktop you point to a data source as normal, build & then publish a report. The web service will recognize the data source as available through the gateway, and the report will be refreshable on the web. There's no special setup involved once the gateway is configured.

Comment: hi, I use the on premise data gateway and not personal

Comment: here is the tutorial used: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-onprem/

Comment: I used the odbc to setup, it says connected, but when refreshing through the webservice it did not get the latest (assuming it still using the connection string done from the dektop version and not using the data gateway connection)

Comment: On PowerBI.com, if you click the cog at the top right and select Manage Gateways, do you see the gateway you created? Are you able to test the connection successfully? Do you get any error when you refresh your dataset (on the bottom left on PowerBI.com)?